# Why does reading a .txt file with Python results in a blank line in the console?

Tags: python, file-io

I am at a part of a tutorial where I'm reading a .txt file. I followed the instructions key for key, but my console log is returning a blank line.

Does anyone know what could be off?

```
employee_file = open('employees.txt', 'r')

print(employee_file.readline())

employee_file.close()
```

Comment: Could it be that your `employees.txt` file is empty?

Comment: What is the first line of your text file?

Comment: That only reads one line. Did you mean `readlines`?

Comment: I did readlines and it printed an open and closed bracket in my console. The file isn't empty, I made sure to make a .txt file to use! My first line is Jim- Sales

Comment: `open('employees.txt', 'r')` assumes the file is in the current working directory. Try giving the full path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
with open ('employees.txt') as file :
    for line in file :
        print (line)
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you work in the same path where the file is,
Use this:
    print(os.getcwd())
Second make sure that file is not empty and save it.
Third Use Code written by @bashBedlam and it should work.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that in the same console session, you already opened and read the file *but forgot to close it*. Then you re-ran the same `readline` or `readlines()` which would return empty because the file pointer is already at the end of the file.

```
$ cat employees.txt
Jim-Sales
111
222

$ python3.7
Python 3.7.2 (default, Mar  8 2019, 19:01:13) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> employee_file = open('employees.txt', 'r')
>>> print(employee_file.readline())
Jim-Sales

>>> print(employee_file.readlines())
['111\n', '222\n']
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> print(employee_file.readline())

>>> print(employee_file.readlines())
[]
```

That's why the recommended practice is to always [wrap it in a `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

```
>>> with open("employees.txt", "r") as employee_file:
...      print(employee_file.readlines())
... 
['Jim-Sales\n', '111\n', '222\n']
>>> with open("employees.txt", "r") as employee_file:
...      print(employee_file.readlines())
... 
['Jim-Sales\n', '111\n', '222\n']
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `seek()` function of file object.

This sets the file's current position at the offset, may be the cursor in your file is at last position, because of this you are getting nothing.

update your code:

```
employee_file = open('employees.txt', 'r')
employee_file.seek(0)  # Sets cursor in your file at absolute position (At beginning)

print(employee_file.readline())
```

This should work.